# Include all columns with custom aggregation function in dplyr summarize

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataframe that has a structure similar to the one given below. The main task is to separate strings with ampersands ("&") and return a new dataframe that's twice as long with two rows for the value on either side of the ampersand. This can be achieved with `dplyr::summarize` as shown below.

However, my problem is that I must manually specify and then `rep()` all of the other columns (in this case `val1` and `val2`) to keep them in the resultant dataframe. I am wondering if there is a way to automatically include the values from the other columns so that I needn't manually specify them.

To be clear, I am not looking for alternate ways to split the strings. I am only interested ways to create the new dataframe while preserving the values from all other columns.

```r
# Create Data
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(string = paste0(LETTERS,"&",rev(letters)),val1 = 1:26,val2 = 26:1)
```

Working version that can't scale to many other columns:

```r
cleaner <- function(string,val1,val2){
  split <- strsplit(string,"&")
  # Create a vector of everything before the &
  string1 <- sapply(split,"[[",1)
  # Create a vector of everything after the &
  string2 <- sapply(split,"[[",2)
  
  # Assemble results, preserving other columns
  tibble(string = c(string1,string2),
         val1 = rep(val1,2),
         val2 = rep(val2,2))
}

summarize(df,cleaner(string,val1,val2))
```

This produces the correct output, but I am wishing for code that produces the same output but looks something like:

```r
cleaner <- function(string,...){
  split <- strsplit(string,"&")
  string1 <- sapply(split,"[[",1)
  string2 <- sapply(split,"[[",2)
  
  # Assemble results, automatically preserving other columns
  tibble(string = c(string1,string2),...)
}

summarize(df,cleaner(string,...))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cbind` which allows for combinations

```
cbind(string = sort(unlist(strsplit(df$string,"&")), method = "radix"), df[-1])
```

```
   string val1 val2
1       A    1   26
2       B    2   25
3       C    3   24
4       D    4   23
5       E    5   22
6       F    6   21
7       G    7   20
8       H    8   19
9       I    9   18
10      J   10   17
11      K   11   16
12      L   12   15
13      M   13   14
14      N   14   13
15      O   15   12
16      P   16   11
17      Q   17   10
18      R   18    9
19      S   19    8
20      T   20    7
21      U   21    6
22      V   22    5
23      W   23    4
24      X   24    3
25      Y   25    2
26      Z   26    1
27      a    1   26
28      b    2   25
29      c    3   24
30      d    4   23
31      e    5   22
32      f    6   21
33      g    7   20
34      h    8   19
35      i    9   18
36      j   10   17
37      k   11   16
38      l   12   15
39      m   13   14
40      n   14   13
41      o   15   12
42      p   16   11
43      q   17   10
44      r   18    9
45      s   19    8
46      t   20    7
47      u   21    6
48      v   22    5
49      w   23    4
50      x   24    3
51      y   25    2
52      z   26    1
```

Comment: This is very close, with a few exceptions. First, `unlist(stringsplit(string))` is not ideal in this context because it does not preserve the vector in the right order--that's why I use the `sapply` in my original post. My goal is to avoid manually specifying the other `val1` and `val2` columns at all. This can be achieved by removing the `...`, `arguments`, and `cbind` from the `cleaner` function and then rewriting the last line as: `reframe(df,cleaner(string,val1=val1, val2=val2)) |> cbind(df |> select(-string))`. If you update the post with these (or something better), I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 0):

You want this?:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  # separate_rows("string") %>%  # separate_rows() has been superseded
  separate_longer_delim(string, "&") %>% 
  arrange(string) 


 string  val1  val2
   <chr>  <int> <int>
 1 A          1    26
 2 B          2    25
 3 C          3    24
 4 D          4    23
 5 E          5    22
 6 F          6    21
 7 G          7    20
 8 H          8    19
 9 I          9    18
10 J         10    17
11 K         11    16
12 L         12    15
13 M         13    14
14 N         14    13
15 O         15    12
16 P         16    11
17 Q         17    10
18 R         18     9
19 S         19     8
20 T         20     7
21 U         21     6
22 V         22     5
23 W         23     4
24 X         24     3
25 Y         25     2
26 Z         26     1
27 a         26     1
28 b         25     2
29 c         24     3
30 d         23     4
31 e         22     5
32 f         21     6
33 g         20     7
34 h         19     8
35 i         18     9
36 j         17    10
37 k         16    11
38 l         15    12
39 m         14    13
40 n         13    14
41 o         12    15
42 p         11    16
43 q         10    17
44 r          9    18
45 s          8    19
46 t          7    20
47 u          6    21
48 v          5    22
49 w          4    23
50 x          3    24
51 y          2    25
52 z          1    26
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I didn't know about this function! However, in reality the task is more complicated than just splitting at ampersands and requires a dedicated function. I am wondering if I can keep the other columns within the constraint of applying a custom function.

Comment: What about: `df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(cleaner(.$string, .$val1, .$val2)) %>%
  ungroup()` or `df %>% 
  mutate(string = str_split(string, "&")) %>% 
  unnest(string)`

Comment: Your first commented suggestion is closer to what I'm looking for. However, the key is that I want to apply some sort of `cleaner(string,...)` without having to manually specify all of the other columns in the dataframe. Said another way, I would like the column-preserving functionality of `mutate` with the row-adding functionality of `summarize`